# wxPython Panel Text Not Rendering

Tags: text, wxpython, rendering, panel, wxwidgets

The problem I'm having is that when I set the static text inside a panel (see #Case 2) it only renders the first letter. The code below is a super stripped down version of my actual code but it produces an identical result:

```
import wx
import time

class TestInterface(wx.Frame):

    testStatusFlag = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(TestInterface, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.pnl = wx.Panel(self)

        self.SetSize((450, 225))
        self.SetTitle('example')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

        self.indicatorFullTest = None
        self.buttonFullTest = None
        self.setTestStatus(status=1) 


    def runTest(self, ev=None):

        self.setTestStatus(status=2)

        #the test is a bunch of functions that take a bunch of time to run
        #they're all located in separate files but all access a single piece of hardware
        #so multithreading is effectively impossible (I don't want to spend days re-writing stuff to accomodate it)
        time.sleep(10)

        self.setTestStatus(status=3)
        return 0


    def setTestStatus(self, ev=None, status=None):

        #Handle the optional status argument
        if (status in [1,2,3]):
            self.testStatusFlag = status

        #Remove any old stuff since if we're calling this function they have to get removed
        if (self.indicatorFullTest != None):
            self.indicatorFullTest.Hide()
        if (self.buttonFullTest != None):
            self.buttonFullTest.Hide()

        #Case 1
        if (self.testStatusFlag == 1):
            self.buttonFullTest = wx.Button( self.pnl, label='Run Test', pos=(125, 100), size=(250, 50))  
            self.buttonFullTest.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.runTest)

        #Case 2
        elif (self.testStatusFlag == 2):
            self.indicatorFullTest = wx.Panel( self.pnl, pos=(125, 100), size=(250, 50))
            wx.StaticText(self.indicatorFullTest, wx.ID_ANY, "Full-Board Test now in progress\nAllow up to 6 min to finish...",
                                                  style=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL, pos=(18,7))
            self.indicatorFullTest.SetBackgroundColour( 'Tan' )
            self.Update()

        #Case 3
        elif (self.testStatusFlag == 3):
            self.buttonFullTest = wx.Button( self.pnl, label='Test Complete\nPress to reset GUI', 
                                             pos=(125, 100), size=(250, 50) )
            self.buttonFullTest.SetBackgroundColour( (130,255,130) )
            self.buttonFullTest.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.resetGUI)


    #Resets the GUI after a test is complete
    def resetGUI(self, ev=None):
        self.setTestStatus(status=1) #Reset the fullTest button/indicator thing



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex = wx.App()
    gui = TestInterface(None)
    ex.MainLoop()
```

Basically, how do I make the UI fully render the text? I imagine it has something to do with not going back to wx's main loop after changing that indicator, but I feel like calling self.Update() should make that unnecessary. It may also have something to do with how I'm switching between using a button and using a panel (which is probably bad but I'm not sure how else to do it). I know that I could solve this by making my test function run in a separate thread but the problem is that the test function calls separate libraries which I literally do not have the time to re-write.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit easier when you use wxPython's sizers because then you can just Show and Hide widgets. You can see a good example in this [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/). I would recommend learning sizers just to make your UI more dynamic when you resize the frame.

But regardless, the answer to this conundrum is pretty simple. Instead of calling self.Update() in Case #2, you need to call **wx.Yield()**. I swapped that one line change in and it worked for me on Linux.